# Error running google tool kit for mac unit test

Tags: iphone, xcode, unit-testing, ios

I am trying to install google toolkit for mac, everything is setup as advised here : http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting
but  when I try to compile I get this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   ‘NSInternalInconsistencyException’,
>   reason: ‘Could not load NIB in bundle:
>   ‘NSBundle  (loaded)’ with name
>   ‘MainWindow’‘

Any suggestions..? what am I missing...?

**EDIT : ** Solution is to add your .xib file to the unit test target you have.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution is to modify your unit testing target to not try and load the MainWindow nib:

- Open your unit testing Target's info page
- Switch to Properties tab
- clear the contents of the "Main Nib File" textbox (it will probably have "MainWindow" before you clear it).

Answer (score 0):

You mean when you run, not when you compile?

Are you sure you've created the proper type of application? The MainWindow.xib file is created by Xcode when creating a new project.

Comment: When I try to compile for unit test I get this error. I got it working by adding it to unit test target. thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Delete MainWindow.xib from the project-info.plist file.